# Should cycles in direct product group be disjoint?

Tags: direct-product, permutation-cycles

Suppose $ G_{1}, \dots, G_{d}$ are permutation groups.

Given $ G_{i}$ some finite groups for $ i=1,...,d$, we define the direct product group $ G_{1}\times ... \times G_{d} $ as the Cartesian product, $ G_{1} \times ... \times G_{d} $ $^{1}$ where multiplication is defined coordinate-wise
$   (g_{1},...,g_{d}) \cdot  (g_{1}^{\prime},...,g_{d}^{\prime}) =  (g_{1} \cdot g^{\prime}_{1},...,g_{d} \cdot g_{d}^{\prime})$.

My question is:

> Should the generators of $ G_{1}, ... , G_{d}$ be disjoint? Can you give me any reference please?

I think they must be disjoint since the underlying set must is partitioned .

---

$^1$ That is, the ordered d-tuples $ (g_{1},...,g_{d}) $, where $ g_{1}\in G_{1} $ ,..., $ g_{d}\in G_{d}$.

Comment: Have you looked at special cases? For example $S_2\times S_2$? [Its elements by your definition are $\{(e,e), (e,(12)),((12),e), ((12),(12))\}$.]

Comment: the the underlying set {1,2} is not Cartesian product in this case

Comment: "Should the generators of $G_1, \dots, G_d$ be disjoint?" Generators of $G_i$ are elements of $G_i$ so they are disjoint from generators of $G_j$ for $j \neq i$. I'm not sure this is the question you intended to ask. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user9272398 : I used your definition. You have said you have a cartesian product of permutation groups, you haven't said these permutation groups act on disjoint sets. You really do have to clarify what your question is.